# Django- How to use one field from one model to another model?

Tags: django, django-models

I have 2 models `GeneralUser` & `UserVoteNews` which uses User as foreign key. I want to add a Boolean field in the `GeneralUser`, and want to access it in the `UserVoteNews` model. How  can I achieve this?

```
class GeneralUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ban = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class UserVoteNews(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ban = ??
```

Comment: well, since a `User` can have multiple `GeneralUser` associated with it, there isn't **one single value** of `ban` for any user. So there isn't a value you can access. Which value do you want?

Comment: I want the ban value for each user.id

Comment: There isn't one ban value for each user.id, there can be multiple ban values. Which one do you want?

Comment: one user can have multiple `GeneralUser` instance. Which one's ban value you want?

Comment: My bad, I phrased in wrong. In want ban value for each General user instance @ruddra

Comment: In your case, your database is irregular. It is a bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a field, use a [property](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-property-function/) method:

```
# for every ban value

class UserVoteNews(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @property
    def ban(self):
       return self.user.generaluser.values('pk', 'ban')

# for latest ban value
class UserVoteNews(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @property
    def ban(self):
       return self.user.generaluser.last().ban

# For any ban value

class UserVoteNews(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @property
    def ban(self):
       return self.user.generaluser.filter(ban=True).exists()
```

But it would be good design if you had [**`OneToOne`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField) relation between `GeneralUser` and `User` model. Then you could simply use:

```
@property
def ban(self):
   return self.user.generaluser.ban
```

Comment: Can you help me with understanding the differences between every ban value, latest ban value and any ban value?

Comment: Also, I am not acknowledged with the best practices. If possible give me some resources!

Comment: OneToOne field gives a restriction where you can't create multiple GeneralUser instance with one User object. And it will also give you an advantage over accessing instance in reverse way. Like you can access `GeneralUser` instance from `User` via `user_object.generaluser`.

Comment: every ban value will return a dictionary with general user id and ban status. Latest ban will return the last `GeneralUser` instance's ban status which was created for a single user. And last one will return True if there is any general user instance which was banned

Answer (score 1):

I would make single model for ban field. And so on

```
class allUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    ban = models.BooleanField(default=True) 


class GeneralUser(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(allUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
class UserVoteNews(models.Model):
    user =models.ForeignKey(allUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```